# How do I 'enable' a user control that already has datacontext defined?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Having difficulty getting a certain UI behavior. I have two user controls defined. The first control simply goes and gets the path of a database to open. I want the second control to be enabled when a path is selected. Here is my XAML...

```
   <advanced2:LoadOnDemandDemoControl BorderBrush="#FFA1BD17" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="290" Margin="25,34,0,52"
            DataContext="{Binding SourceTree}"  IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=pathName, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}">
        <advanced2:LoadOnDemandDemoControl.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFCFB0B0" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </advanced2:LoadOnDemandDemoControl.Background>
    </advanced2:LoadOnDemandDemoControl>

    <advanced2:PathSelector x:Name="pathName" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,61,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.53,1.6"></advanced2:PathSelector>
```

Comment: And the problem is ....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a property trigger to `Enable` your control when there is text in `pathName` control.

You can use `elementName` to find your source control.

You can do https://stackoverflow.com/a/822961/1011959